# Getting the "VERSION NAME" of a flavor from an aar

Tags: android, android-productflavors

I am using a library where I want to extract the app version of the app that is using it, everything was fine with reflection

```
Class.forName(context.getPackageName() + ".BuildConfig");
```

But then... I separated the app to flavors, the library now can't find the BuildConfig class, it always throws "Class not found Exception" ... Debugging I noticed that the version name that I want it's with the default project id or the physical name where my classes are, not the flavor app id.

Here is my config of the gradle.

```
productFlavors {
    development {
        applicationId "com.dev.testit"
        buildConfigField 'String', 'API', '"api"'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.N'
    }
    production {
        applicationId "com.testit"
        buildConfigField 'String', 'API', '"prod"'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.S'
    }
}
```

Is there a way?

Thank you

Comment: Why not have the app pass the version name into the library, via a constructor parameter, method call, etc.?

Comment: I was thinking that for my last solution, but I want it to be a little bit more automatic if it's possible.

Comment: If this library is for your own personal use, you seem to be over-engineering the problem, IMHO. Similarly IMHO, if this library is for wider use, you should not be assuming anything about the app environment, such as where the `BuildConfig` class resides and whether `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` is the value that the developer wants you to use (instead of a string resource, for translations).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getAppVersionName(Context context) {
    if (context == null) 
        return null;

    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();

    try {
        PackageInfo info = packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        return info.versionName;

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Refer to the [doc here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html).

Comment: Not working. It passes the dev id of the flavor... and it's always exception. :/